# Gridview control - Hiding and showing columns

Tags: asp.net

Is there any setting in gridview control to hide a template feild in normal mode but show the hidden feild in edit item template.

Thanks

Comment: do u want to hide a whole column or just one field ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide a column use ie. `GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;`. Be aware that it will NOT be data-bound so you cannot use a hidden column to retrieve some values you do not want to user to see, like you could with the old `DataGrid`.

To show a field just on the row that is being editted, add a `TemplateField` with an empty `ItemTemplate`, and a filled `EditTemplate`.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

the grid view is tabular data so you would either show or hide the column regardless of the state of a single row. if you want to dynamically control the layout a `listview` control would be a better option.